# the_post_thumbnail do 2 queries. How to optimize

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I have query:

```
<?php
      $args =  array( 'post_type' => 'post',
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                     'orderby' => 'post_date',
                     'order' => 'DESC',
                     'showposts' => 10
                     );
      $recent = new WP_Query($args);
      $TopnewsIndex1 = 0;
      while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
         array_push($index_posts, $recent->post->ID);
         $ptitle = esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ));
         $pdesc  = esc_attr( get_post_field( 'sub_desc', $post_id ));
?>

<h2> <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' rel='bookmark'> <?php echo $ptitle ?></a>  </h2>
<p><?php echo $pdesc; ?></p>

<?php      endwhile; ?>
```

And after that get_num_queries() = 1 queries (for 10 posts)

If I wont to show thumb images for each posts I add string:

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
```

And after that get_num_queries() = 21 queries (1 + 10*2)

If in one page I wont to show 50 post with thumb then num queries = 101 queries!!!

Do you have any idea why? How to optimize this code?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I see, its a older post

Answer (score 1):

use caching plugins, that is why they exist - to offload work from the DB.

If you don't want to do full page caching and you know that the resulting HTML do not change much you can use [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store the result for something like an hour before recalculating it.